# How to load SpringBoot properties into log4j.xml

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to load a property from application.properties to my log4j setting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" strict="true" >
  <Properties>
      <Property name="dirname">${application:log.directory}</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Filter type="ThresholdFilter" level="debug"/>
 
  <Appenders>
    <Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
      <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%m%n"/>
      <!-- 
      <Filters>
        <Filter type="MarkerFilter" marker="FLOW" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <Filter type="MarkerFilter" marker="EXCEPTION" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
      </Filters>
       -->
    </Appender>

    <Appender type="RollingFile" name="myapp" fileName="${dirname}/myapp.log" 
              filePattern="${dirname}/myapp-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz" >
          <Strategy type="DefaultRolloverStrategy" max="5" />
    </Appender>

 
  <Loggers>

    
    <Logger name="mylogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="myapp"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="debug">
          <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="myapp" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
 
</Configuration>
```

And my application.properties have the setting

```
log.directory=C:/temp/log
```

It's not working as I expected. How to make this working?

Answer (score 0):

I find answer by myself. Put this setting in the log4j.xml

```
  <Properties>
      <Property name="dirname">${bundle:application:log.directory</Property>
  </Properties>
```